# How can I load the connection string from App.config or WebConfig.config in Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

In the old versions I can give the connection string directly in the DbContext constructor.

Example in EF v6:
My connection string in the App.config is given below:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DatabaseConnecionString"
    connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=db;Integrated Security=true"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

---

```
var myDbContext = MyDbContext("name=DatabaseConnecionString");
```

When I do the same thing with EF 7 / Core I get an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Entity Framework 7/Core, you cannot pass the connection string name to the DbContext base constructor like in the past but there is another solution for the problem.

Solution I:

```
var optionsBuilder = new Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptionsBuilder();
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnecionString"].ConnectionString;
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
 using (var dbContext = new DatabaseContext(optionsBuilder.Options))
 {
    dbContext.Users.Add(new User() { Name = "Bassam" });
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
 }
```

Solution II:

If you want to use the provided connection string for the database migrations, then you have to put the loading in the DbContext.

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
      var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnecionString"].ConnectionString;
      optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    }

    public DatabaseContext()
    {
    }

    public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions s)
    : base(s)
    {
    }
}
```

If the App.config is not in your Assembly(dll/exe) then you have to give the the startup project with the data migration command Add-Migration/Update-Migration.

Answer (score 0):

On dotnet core 5.0 it should be done like this

```
var optionsBuilder = new Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDBContext>();
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppDb"].ConnectionString;
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
context = new MyDBContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
```

AppDb is connection string name in App.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="AppDb" connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1;Database=databaseName;Trusted_Connection=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;User Id=dbUser;password=dbUserPassword;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```